# Firefox (Gecko) code - interrogating the cache - how do I get a list of devices?

Tags: firefox, caching, gecko

Referring to nsICacheService (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsICacheService) and nsICacheVisitor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsICacheVisitor):

1. Where do I get an instance of nsICacheVisitor?
2. Where do I get a list of devices so that I can call visitEntry() and visitDevice()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nsICacheVisitor is an interface that you implement and pass to the [visitEntries method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsICacheService#visitEntries.28.29) on nsICacheService.  See [this test file](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/test/TestCacheVisitor.js) for example code.